# How to filter an array by a condition

Tags: php, arrays, filter, higher-order-functions

I have an array like this:

```
array("a" => 2, "b" => 4, "c" => 2, "d" => 5, "e" => 6, "f" => 2)
```

Now I want to filter that array by some condition and only keep the elements where the value is equal to 2 and delete all elements where the value is NOT 2.

So my expected result array would be:

```
array("a" => 2, "c" => 2, "f" => 2)
```

<sub>Note: I want to keep the keys from the original array.</sub>

How can I do that with PHP? Any built-in functions?

Comment: Check out the example on the [`array_filter`](http://php.net/array_filter) page.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

```
$fullArray = array('a'=>2,'b'=>4,'c'=>2,'d'=>5,'e'=>6,'f'=>2);


function filterArray($value){
    return ($value == 2);
}

$filteredArray = array_filter($fullArray, 'filterArray');

foreach($filteredArray as $k => $v){
    echo "$k = $v";
}
```

Comment: that ask to make a different function for each request... is it possible to ass an extra var ? (2 as variable)

Comment: It would be nice to update this answer to use a closure, to teach best practices in 2019!

Answer (score 33):

You somehow have to loop through your array and filter each element by your condition. This can be done with various methods.

## Loops [`while`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.while.php) / [`for`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php) / [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) method

Loop through your array with any loop you want, may it be `while`, `for` or `foreach`. Then simply check for your condition and either [`unset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) the elements if they don't meet your condition or write the elements, which meet the condition, into a new array.

#### Looping

```
//while loop
while(list($key, $value) = each($array)){
    //condition
}

//for loop
$keys = array_keys($array);
for($counter = 0, $length = count($array); $counter < $length; $counter++){
    $key = $keys[$counter];
    $value = $array[$key];
    //condition 
}

//foreach loop
foreach($array as $key => $value){
    //condition
}
```

#### Condition

Just place your condition into the loop where the comment `//condition` is. The condition can just check for whatever you want and then you can either `unset()` the elements which don't meet your condition, and reindex the array with [`array_values()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) if you want, or write the elements in a new array which meet the condition.

```
//Pseudo code
//Use one of the two ways
if(condition){  //1. Condition fulfilled
    $newArray[ ] = $value;
            //↑ Put '$key' there, if you want to keep the original keys
            //Result array is: $newArray

} else {        //2. Condition NOT fulfilled
    unset($array[$key]);
    //Use array_values() after the loop if you want to reindex the array
    //Result array is: $array
}
```

## [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) method

Another method is to use the `array_filter()` built-in function. It generally works pretty much the same as the method with a simple loop.

You just need to return `TRUE` if you want to keep the element in the array and `FALSE` if you want to drop the element out of the result array.

```
//Anonymous function
$newArray = array_filter($array, function($value, $key){
    //condition
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH);

//Function name passed as string
function filter($value, $key){
    //condition
}
$newArray = array_filter($array, "filter", ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH);

//'create_function()', NOT recommended
$newArray = array_filter($array, create_function('$value, $key', '/* condition */'), ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH);
```

## [`preg_grep()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php) method

`preg_grep()` is similar to `array_filter()` just that it only uses regular expression to filter the array. So you might not be able to do everything with it, since you can only use a regular expression as filter and you can only filter by values or with some more code by keys.

Also note that you can pass the flag `PREG_GREP_INVERT` as third parameter to invert the results.

```
//Filter by values
$newArray = preg_grep("/regex/", $array);
```

## Common conditions

There are many common conditions used to filter an array of which all can be applied to the value and or key of the array. I will just list a few of them here:

```
//Odd values
return $value & 1;

//Even values
return !($value & 1);

//NOT null values
return !is_null($value);

//NOT 0 values
return $value !== 0;

//Contain certain value values
return strpos($value, $needle) !== FALSE;  //Use 'use($needle)' to get the var into scope

//Contain certain substring at position values
return substr($value, $position, $length) === $subString;

//NOT 'empty'(link) values
array_filter($array);  //Leave out the callback parameter
```

Comment: It doesn't pass $arr by reference, and instead returns a new array which you're not capturing.

Comment: @Simon: The manual is not just for book worms. All developers should be able and smart enough to read it. But maybe most expect a copy & paste example where they don’t have to think.

Answer (score 3):

You can iterate on the copies of the keys to be able to use `unset()` in the loop:

```
foreach (array_keys($array) as $key) {
    if ($array[$key] != 2)  {
        unset($array[$key]);
    }
}
```

The advantage of this method is memory efficiency if your array contains big values - they are not duplicated.

**EDIT** I just noticed, that you actually only need the keys that have a value of 2 (you already know the value):

```
$keys = array();
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if ($value == 2)  {
        $keys[] = $key;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work, but I'm not sure how efficient it is as you probably end up copying a lot of data.

```
$newArray = array_intersect_key(
                  $fullarray, 
                  array_flip(array_keys($fullarray, 2))
            );
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the snappiest, readable built-in function is: [array_intersect()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php)

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/cSraG))

```
$array = array("a" => 2, "b" => 4, "c" => 2, "d" => 5, "e" => 6, "f" => 2);
var_export(array_intersect($array, [2]));
```

Output:

```
array (
  'a' => 2,
  'c' => 2,
  'f' => 2,
)
```

Just make sure you declare the 2nd parameter as an array because that is the value type expected.

Now there is nothing wrong with writing out a foreach loop, or using `array_filter()`, they just have a more verbose syntax.

`array_intersect()` is also very easy to extend (include additional "qualifying" values) by adding more values to the 2nd parameter array.

---

From PHP7.4, arrow function syntax is available. This affords more concise code and the ability to access global variables without `use`.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/PXDuJ))

```
$haystack = [
    "a" => 2,
    "b" => 4,
    "c" => 2,
    "d" => 5,
    "e" => 6,
    "f" => 2
];
$needle = 2;

var_export(
    array_filter(
        $haystack,
        fn($v) => $v === $needle
    )
);
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be handled using a closure. The following answer is inspired by [PHP The Right Way](https://phptherightway.com/pages/Functional-Programming.html):

```
//This will create an anonymous function that will filter the items in the array by the value supplied
function cb_equal_to($val)
{
    return function($item) use ($val) {
        return $item == $val;
    };
}

$input = array("a" => 2, "b" => 4, "c" => 2, "d" => 5, "e" => 6, "f" => 2);

// Use array_filter on a input with a selected filter function
$filtered_array = array_filter($input, cb_equal_to(2));
```

Contents of $filtered_array would now be

```
array ( ["a"] => 2 ["c"] => 2 ["f"] => 2 )
```

Answer (score 0):

I might do something like:

```
$newarray = array();
foreach ($jsonarray as $testelement){
    if ($testelement == 2){$newarray[]=$testelement}
}
$result = count($newarray);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  foreach ($aray as $key => $value) {
    if (2 != $value) {
      unset($array($key));
    }
  }

  echo 'Items in array:' . count($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```php
$array = array("a" => 2, "b" => 4, "c" => 2, "d" => 5, "e" => 6, "f" => 2);
$arrayFiltered = array_filter($array, function ($element) {
    return $element == 2;
});
```

or:

```
$arrayFiltered = array_filter($array, fn($element) => $element == 2);
```