# Remove elements from a flat array if value is greater than a given number

Tags: php, arrays, filtering

1. List item

What's the most efficient way to remove items from an array in php where the value is greater than a pre-determined threshold, e.g. given an array

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1.639
    [1] => 2.168
    [4] => 1.897
    [6] => 4.129
)
```

I would like to remove all the items with a value greater than e.g. 2, preserving key associations, to give

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1.639
    [4] => 1.897
)
```

I know I can do this using a `foreach()` loop but it seems that there should be a more elegant way.

Comment: Related: [How to filter an array by a condition](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1503579/2943403)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No matter what you use, the array has to be looped through but you can hide it by using `array_filter`:

```
$data = array_filter($data, fn($var) => $var < 2);
```

Comment: +1. I was going to suggest the same, though using array_walk, which is the wrong function for doing it. I forgot about array_filter... (array_walk should also pass the key and the actual array by reference, probably results in weird behaviour.) The solution you posted looks way better. :)