# PHP groupBy array search

Tags: php, arrays, search

I want to search in an array like SQL queries and I have no idea how to do that.
Here is my array:

```
$array = array(
    'app' => 'apple',
    'ban' => 'banana',
    'lem' => 'lemon',
    'ora' => 'orange',
);
```

when I search for `%an%` should return this:

```
$array = array(
    'ban' => 'banana',
    'ora' => 'orange',
);
```

and when I search for `%or%` should return this:

```
$array = array(
    'ora' => 'orange'
);
```

I mean search in both key and value of array

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1503579/3933332 or look at `preg_grep()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution using `array_filter` function:

```
$search_word = "an";  // dynamic search word
$search_result = array_filter($array, function($v) use($search_word){
    return strpos($v, $search_word) !== false; 
});

print_r($search_result);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [2] => banana
    [4] => orange
)
```

---

*Additional approach:*

Since PHP 5.6 we are able to filter arrays both by key and value using `array_filter` with `ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH` flag :

```
$array = array(
    'app' => 'apple',
    'ban' => 'banana',
    'lem' => 'lemon',
    'ora' => 'orange',
);

$search_word = "a";
$search_result = array_filter($array, function($v, $k) use($search_word){
    return strpos($v, $search_word) !== false || strpos($k, $search_word) !== false; 
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH);

print_r($search_result);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [app] => apple
    [ban] => banana
    [ora] => orange
)
```

Comment: This is nice cause you can still include in the search chars that represent stuff for preg...

Comment: @FirstOne what if I want to search in both key and value

Comment: @amiroperator, ok, can you add an appropriate associative input array and the expected output to be more clear? Should it match strictly both key and value or it can be matched with one of them?

Comment: @amiroperator, which version of PHP are you using?

Comment: @amiroperator, anyway, to filter both by key and value you can use `array_filter` with `ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH` flag `$search_result = array_filter($array, function($v, $k) use($search_word){
    return strpos($v, $search_word) !== false || strpos($k, $search_word) !== false; 
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH);`

Comment: @amiroperator, also, if you want to have a strict matching both to key AND value - use this condition `strpos($v, $search_word) !== false && strpos($k, $search_word) !== false;`

Comment: Thanks, This was helpful

Answer (score 1):

Use [`preg_grep`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php) function for this:

```
$array = array(
    1 => 'apple',
    2 => 'banana',
    3 => 'lemon',
    4 => 'orange'
);
print_r(preg_grep('/an/', $array));
// outputs Array ( [2] => banana [4] => orange )
```

Comment: What about searching in key too ?

Comment: Note that this won't work if you need to search for other things such as `an/`.

Answer (score 1):

To search in both keys and values, I think the easiest way is to use a foreach loop.

```
$term = 'an';   // define your search term

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    // check in both key and value using strpos
    if (strpos($key, $term) !== false || strpos($value, $term) !== false) {
        $result[$key] = $value;   // add to search result if found
    }
}
```