# How to return a word from an array which start with N in PHP?

Tags: php

I am new in php,I want to return username from an array which start with character **N**, Can anybody please help me, thanks in advance.

**Ex.**

```
$arr = array("naveen", "paras", "sunil", "nandan");
```

I want to return all username starting with N.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1503579/3933332 You have to filter your array in some way.

Comment: ithink you want like this:-https://eval.in/612745

Comment: Just choose a method how you want to filter your array and then you just apply your condition. Even your condition can be done in multiple ways with `substr()`, `strpos()`, character access, ... or a regex.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

Your code might look something like this:

```
$arr=array("naveen", "paras", "sunil", "nandan");


function startsWithN($var)
{
    return(substr($var,0,1) === "n" || substr($var,0,1) === "N");
}

$result = array_filter($arr, "startsWithN");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr = array("naveen", "paras", "sunil", "nandan");

$response = array();
foreach ($arr as $ar){
  if(substr($ar,0,1) == 'n'){
     response[] = $ar;
  }
}
print_r($response);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: @FrankerZ : Thanks for your kind advice. I will keep it in mind.

Answer (score 0):

you can loop over your array and check if the elements begin with a "n".

```
$resultArray = [];
foreach($arr as $value)
{
    if(strpos($value, 'n') === 0)
    {
        $resultArray[] = $value;
    }
}
print_r($resultArray) // Array which contains all old array elements which begin with a "n"
```

if you dont care about lowercase and uppercase, just change the condition inside the loop a bit:
`if(strpos($value, strtoupper('n')) === 0)`

I hope i could help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the array's element offset and save the results in an array

```
$arr=array("naveen", "paras", "sunil", "nandan");

foreach ($arr as $ar){
  if($ar[0] == 'n'){
    $result[] = $ar;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `array_filter()` and `substr()` functions to get result:

```
$arr=array("naveen", "paras", "sunil", "nandan");
$result = array_filter($arr, function($key) {
  return substr($key, 0, 1) === 'n';
});
print_r($result);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => naveen
    [3] => nandan
)
```