# How can I use array_where in Laravel?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, filter, laravel-5

I have an array (`$payments`) returned by an Eloquent query with the following `JSON` encoded output:

```
[{"id":1, "user_id":"34","amount":"1000","status":"0","created_at":"2016-08-18 14:24:59","updated_at":"2016-08-18 14:24:59"},
{"id":3, "user_id":"33","amount":"300","status":"1","created_at":"2016-08-18 14:31:04","updated_at":"2016-08-18 14:33:20"},
{"id":4, "user_id":"33","amount":"1000","status":"0","created_at":"2016-08-18 14:31:27","updated_at":"2016-08-18 14:31:27"},
{"id":5, "user_id":"34","amount":"400","status":"1","created_at":"2016-08-18 14:42:02","updated_at":"2016-08-18 14:42:02"}]
```

I want to use the `array_where()` method in `Laravel` and filter `$payments` according this condition : `status == 1`, could anyone tell me how to do that?

Comment: IS that an array? Looks like a JSON to me.

Comment: yea it's an array returned by a eloquent query in laravel 5.2

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1503579/3933332

Comment: why not just add to Your database query where('status', '=', 1)   ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is the result of an Eloquent query, it's not an array, it's a [Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-collections). From the documentation:

> All multi-result sets returned by Eloquent are an instance of the `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection` object

You can use the Collection's [`filter`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/collections#method-filter) method, which takes a closure, and return the condition you want (`'status' == 1`) in the closure.

```
$filtered = $your_query_result->filter(function($value, $key) {
    return $value->status == 1;
});
```

Comment: may i ask u the diffrence of collection and array ?

Comment: A Collection is iterable, like an array, but it is an object, with various useful [methods](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-collections#available-methods) that an array doesn't have.

Answer (score 0):

You may be surprised to find out that there is a php function called [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) that does exactly that. Here it is in action

```
$array = [ ['id' => 1, 'status' => 0], ['id' => 2, 'status' => 1], ['id' => 3, 'status' => 0] ];

$array = array_filter($array, function ($item) {
    return $item['status'] == 1;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Eloquents result cannot be json by default unless You call `toJson()` method.

Why not just add to Your database query condition?

Example:

```
$payments = Payment::where('status', '=', 1)->get(); // Payment is model
return response()->json($payments);
```

p.s. it's not recommended to get a big list of json data from db, parse it and filter it.
make better use of database and don't make Your life hard (: