# Deleting an Item from an Array inside another Array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array inside another array - here is my print_r:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ProductID] => 180
            [ProductName] => Male Thread BSPT Coupling
            [ProductImage] => 054-male-thread-bspt-coupling.jpg
            [Termination] => 1/4\"
            [Length] => 58
            [Diameter] => 23
            [Part] => 054CVMT14SNN
            [Price] => 3.26
            [quantity] => 22
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [ProductID] => 183
            [ProductName] => Male Thread BSPT Plug
            [ProductImage] => 054-male-thread-bspt-plug.jpg
            [Termination] => 1/4\"
            [Length] => 38
            [Diameter] =>  
            [Part] => 054PNMT14SXN
            [Price] => 0.67
            [quantity] => 22
        )

)
```

I need to delete from the array where Part = X

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1503579/3933332

Comment: Hi Rizier - Unfortunately I had already been on that page and not found a solution for my array inside and array on PHP 5.3

Comment: Besides that 5.3 is already dead for 2 years it should work. Do you get any error?

Comment: Oh no... sorry even worse - 5.2!!!

Comment: Well this is also covered in the dupe. You then need to define a normal function and pass the function name as string instead of the anonymous function. (Also you need to use the `global` keyword to get variables into scope inside the function)

Comment: Global not mentioned in the dupe!..  So still don't understand why it's a duplicate question!...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this ([demo](https://eval.in/626988)) :

```
    $arr = array(
        'a' => array('h' => 10, 'w' => 40, 'd' => 100, 'part' => 'A10'),
        'b' => array('h' => 20, 'w' => 30, 'd' => 400, 'part' => 'A20'),
        'c' => array('h' => 30, 'w' => 20, 'd' => 900, 'part' => 'A30'),
        'd' => array('h' => 40, 'w' => 10, 'd' => 1600, 'part' => 'A40'),
    );
    $part = 'A10';
    $res = array_filter($arr, function ($elem) use ($part) {
        return $elem['part'] != $part;
    });

    print_r($res);
```

The `$res` will be the input array excluding any item that has its `part` element set to `A10`.

Comment: Hi Ahmad - Thanks very much for this.  Unfortunately the website is on a web server which is using PHP 5.3 and some of this doesn't work on that version.

Comment: how come? array_filter is available since PHP 4 >= 4.0.6. btw closures are available as well since 5.3 :)

Comment: Hi Ahmad, Got this to work now - but it deletes one item and then when I go to delete another one it adds the previous deleted one back in

Comment: can you please show me your code and tell me what do you want to do?

Answer (score -1):

Try this (please notice that this will delete only first occurrence):

```
if(($key = array_search($delPartWithThisId, $partsArray)) !== false) {
    unset($partsArray[$key]);
}
```

Or:

`foreach (array_keys($partsArray, $delPartWithThisId, true) as $key) {
    unset($partsArray[$key]);
}`

In second solution variable `$delPartWithThisId` can be an array like `[1,2,3]`

Additionally i would suggest to use `array_values()` to reorganize array indexes

Comment: this will search in the original array, for any item which value is `$delPartWithThisId` and then unset its key, but please note that the original array is not one-dimension, the original array is an **array of arrays**