# array multidimentional search return all multiple keys

Tags: php

I have this array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 15bw83nfo3wg4
            [date] => 2019-01-01
            [d_c] => D
            [D] => 76181734.95
            [C] => 0.00
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 15byrr7fo3wg4
            [date] => 2019-01-02
            [d_c] => D
            [D] => 4000000.00
            [C] => 0.00
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 15bzwubfo3wg4
            [date] => 2019-01-02
            [d_c] => K
            [D] => 0.00
            [C] => 1585500.00
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 15c0vlvfo3wg4
            [date] => 2019-01-02
            [d_c] => K
            [D] => 0.00
            [C] => 10000000.00
```

How can i search in that array with **date** as parameter value and return **ALL** array which contains the parameter value?

I already tried this:

```
$date = '2019-01-02';
$key = array_search($date, array_column($data, 'date'));
$result = $data[$key];
```

but the result I'm getting is just:

```
[1] => Array
     (
        [id] => 15byrr7fo3wg4
        [date] => 2019-01-02
        [d_c] => D
        [D] => 4000000.00
        [C] => 0.00
     )
```

Comment: @u_mulder how is this a duplicate? Knowing that he's looking to get multiple keys.

Comment: @u_mulder if its a duplicate that of this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1503579/how-to-filter-an-array-by-a-condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use array_filter function

```
$result = array_filter($data, function($x) use ($date) { return $x['date'] == $date; });
```

Answer (score 0):

You only get one result because your `$key` variable only returns the first found element, to get multiple you need to use :

```
array_keys(array_column($array, 'date'), "2019-01-02")
```

Which will return a list of keys containing the keys in the array you're looking for.

Then you can loop through them :

```
$array = [["id" => 1, "date" => "2019-01-02"],["id" => 2, "date" => "2019-01-03"],["id" => 3, "date" => "2019-01-02"],["id" => 4, "date" => "2019-01-05"]];

$date = '2019-01-02';

$keys = array_keys(array_column($array, 'date'), "2019-01-02");

$results = [];

foreach ($keys as $key) {
    $results[] = $array[$key];
}

var_dump($results);
```