# Remove certain elements from an array that fit a condition in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, if-statement

So i have an a array of numbers:

```
$arr = [53, 182, 435, 591, 637];
```

All i am trying to do is loop trough each element and when a certain condition is true it should return a new array with the elements removed that have fitted the condition.

```
foreach($arr as $arry){
  echo "\n";
  echo $arry;
  
  if($arry % 13 == 0){
    //Remove 182 and 637 because they are divisible by 13,and make a new array: [53, 435, 591]
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to filter an array by a condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1503579/how-to-filter-an-array-by-a-condition)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[array_filter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) is ideal for this case.

```php
$arr = [53, 182, 435, 591, 637];

$filtered_arr = array_filter($arr, fn($number) => $number % 13 !== 0);

print_r($filtered_arr);  // [53, 435, 591]
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/l6e2v)

*Note that the short callback [fn](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arrow.php) is only available in PHP7.4 or higher*

Answer (score 2):

Does this answer your question?

```
$arr = [53, 182, 435, 591, 637];

for($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++){
  if($arr[$i] % 13 == 0){
    unset($arr[$i]);
  }
}
$arr = array_values($arr); //reset indexes
```

Comment: I didn't want to comment before the OP decides which answer to accept to not influence his choice. But this solution needs to be optimized because it looping through the array twice while one loop is enough. The built in function `array_filter` seems the be the best for this case but you still can limit your solution to only use the `for` loop and dismiss the use of `array_values`